# how to go to specfic activity using webview in android

Tags: android

I am using the android webview. I need to verify the user from my website. I am using webView. I need back to specify the activity after verifying the user from my website. I have used the bellow like:

```
         var url = "https://sandbox.com/api?redirect_uri=https://www.example.com";
       var webView:WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        webView.loadUrl(url)
        val webSettings = webView.settings
        webSettings.userAgentString = Locale.ENGLISH.toString()
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, urlNewString: String?): Boolean {

                return false
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
                }
            }

        }
```

**How to set redirect_uri to go to specific activity?**
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebView method addJavascriptInterface for example you can read more on this https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview

first step :

```
class WebAppInterface(private val mContext: Context) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun showToast(yourParamForActivity: String) {
        startActivity(yourParamForActivity);
    }
}
```

second :

```
val webView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
webView.addJavascriptInterface(WebAppInterface(this), "Android")
```

last :

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(yourParamForActivity) {
        Android.showToast(yourParamForActivity);
    }
</script>
```